# Make 2-way TLS call to REST API from Java web application

Tags: java, spring, ssl

My biggest issue is that I do not have the certificate (public and private key pair). The certificate is installed in the weblogic trust store and is the default certificate presented when making a request to the web application I am just not sure how I can make the call without the certificate loaded on the file system.

I tried using Apache HTTP client and Javax Http Client hoping that when I would make the call it would also send the certificate.

```
private void testCall(String path) {
    URI uri = null;

    try {
        uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost("secure.url.com")
                .setPath("/"+path)
                .build();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        status = "Error Occured Building URL";
    }
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    builtUrl = httpget.getURI().toString();
    printContent(httpget);

}

private void printContent(HttpGet getRequest){
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        status = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        contentRes = EntityUtils.toString(entity );

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        status = "Error Occured during Client Protocol" + e.toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        status = "Error Occured during Parse Protocol" + e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        status = "Error Occured during Client Protocol" + e.toString();
    }

}
```